# Copy SQL Database from one iPad to another

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, migration

I have written an app (not yet published to the app store - it's in Beta ) that uses core data to store stuff.

I've been using it to store 'real' data for the last week, and this week I'm getting the new iPad Air.

When I install the app onto the iPad Air, it will - of course - have a blank database.

Is there some tool / app, I can use to copy the sql database from my iPad mini onto the iPad Air and then the iPad Air will have the full populated database with no integrity issues?

I have 'iExplore' so I know I can get access to the files, but I just wondered if someone else had tried something similar.

I know I should probably (and eventually want to) implement iCloud however I'm at Uni, and SUPPOSEDLY studying for something entirely unrelated to App Development and don't have the time to learn all of that at the same time. So, really I'm looking for a 'quick fix' without having to manually type everything back in again.

Ideas? Thoughts?

Comment: Side note - your eventual customers will want the same feature. Your app needs to let users transfer data from the start or they won't be happy.

Comment: I know that. I even SAID that. See above? I said I want to add iCloud support, but there are bigger priorities...

Comment: And how many core data backed apps on the App Store allow it? Not many that's for sure!

Comment: I didn't say anything about iCloud. There are many different ways to allow a user to backup data from one device and restore into the app on another device. You don't have to implement real-time data sync via iCloud for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the sqlite database file from your current device, add it to your app's bundle, then add some code to copy it to the location where the database normally lives (before initializing core data).

To grab the sql database from your current device:
Connect your device with the app installed to you Mac. In the Xcode Organizer, select Devices, then under your device listed on the left, select Applications. You should see your application listed in the main (right hand) panel. Select the application, then on the bottom, Download. When prompted tell it where to save and what to name it. Right-click on the file and select 'Show Package Contents'. From there, you can traverse to the location of your sqlite database and do whatever you wish with it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out this week. If it works I'll mark as answered!